# Drupal: automatic relationship between content types

Tags: drupal, relationship, autofill, entityreference

I have 2 content types in Drupal: one "publications" and one "authors".
In "authors" I have several nodes corresponding to several authors: "John", "Linda", "Susan" (for eg.);
In "publications" I have one field named "pub authors" of type "Entity Reference" which fetches names from "authors" nodes.
That means that I can create new content of type "publications" and on the "pub authors" field insert authors from "authors".

Now I would like Drupal to automatically add the new publication to the authors page. I.e., if I added several publications with "John" on the "pub authors" field, I would like the "John" page to list all publications in which he has participated.
I'm trying with the Entity Reference module and with Relationships in the Views module, but for now, with no success.

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/cer

Comment: Thank you. Completely missed that module, which works perfectly.